# Return number of files at ZIP package with NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express, unzip

Here is my function to get number of files within a ZIP package.

```
// check if .ZIP package contains at least one HTML file and return number of files
function validateArchive(path, callback) {
    var filesCount = 0;

    var unzipParser = unzip.Parse();
    var readStream = fs.createReadStream(path).pipe(unzipParser);
    unzipParser.on('error', function(err) {
        throw err;
    });

    readStream.on('entry', function (entry) {
        var fileName = entry.path;
        var type = entry.type; // 'Directory' or 'File'
        if (type == 'File') {
            var fext = fileName.split('.')[1];
            if (fext === 'html') {
                filesCount++;
            }
        }
        entry.autodrain();
    });

    // returns number of files
    setTimeout(function () {
        callback(filesCount);
    }, 1000);
}
```

As you can see I have a problem with returning number of files because asynchronous process in place.

Any ideas hot to return number of files without using `setTimeout` method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can listen to the `close` event:

```
unzipParser.on('close', function() {
    callback(filesCount);
});
```

which is emitted when the end of zip is reached.